# Jenkins cannot read /home/hudson/.ssh/id_rsa

Tags: jenkins, debian

I installed jenkins this way : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-jenkins-on-debian-9/

Basically `sudo apt install jenkins` while logged as root
I then created a `hudson` user and used `ssh-keygen` to generate a pair of keys.

I then tried to use the public key in the `gerrit-trigger` plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-trigger/)

However it tells me `/home/hudson/.ssh/id_rsa` does not exist.
[image: ssh key]

I'm guessing it's a permission issue. when I use `apt install jenkins` is there a way to specify `in user hudson` ?

Thnaks.

Comment: same thing with the .pub

Comment: make sure you created ssh keys using hudson user.

you can view file using list command: `ls -a /home/hudson`. if you dont find ssh keys there,

run:

*sudo su - hudson* and then run 
*ssh-keygen*

Answer (score 0):

Seems you created ssh keys using root user. You need to create ssh keys while logged in as hudson user or you can change path to `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`

If you want to use hudson user's path, login to hudson user first,

> sudo su - hudson

Then create ssh key pair:

> ssh-keygen

Then you can confirm files using list command

> ls -a /home/hudson/

if you see id_rsa file there, then you can put its address `/home/hudson/id_rsa`

Comment: this is how I created the keys, however they are visible in /home/hudson/.ssh not /home/hudson

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is permission related issue. Please change the permissions of all files in .ssh folder in /var/lib/jenkins to jenkins.

> chown jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh && chown jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/*
>
> chmod 700 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh && chmod 600 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/*

Also make similar configuration for hudson user's ssh key:

> su - hudson
>
> chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins installation created a jenkins user in debian.

I had do `su - jenkins` and then create a ssh key pair for it `ssh-keygen`

Then the jenkins UI is able to read this one located in `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa`